# How to correctly encode/decode Spanish accented characters in C#

Tags: c#, html, winforms, encoding, decoding

In my C# WinForms app I am getting callback messages from C/C++ DLL. Those strings look like this in Wireshark:
"c\303\263mo"

and they look like this when I display it in RichTextBox:
[image]

However, in reality it should look like that:

cómo

So I tried this but it does not work, where 'txt' is the input string:

```
byte[] bytes = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(txt);
byte[] converted = Encoding.Convert(Encoding.Default, Encoding.UTF8, bytes);
txt = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(converted);
```

I do not know what is the encoding of the text that comes in, but Wireshark says:
Line-based text data: text/html (1 lines).
Also, when I get this text in the callback I retrieve it as msg.htmlBody (no other way).
All that makes me think that it has something to do with HTML encoding as well...

Any idea how should I deal with this to be able to display "cómo" ?

Comment: Have you stepped through/debugged your code to see what it looks like at each step?

Comment: I don't think this is a C# problem because your code gives the correct result (start with `var txt = "cómo";`)

Comment: If the dll is in C/C++, can you show us the `extern` that defines the methods? If the dll returns utf8 characters, the best solution is to change them C#-side. Microsoft added a new `UnmanagedType.LPUTF8Str` that perhaps could be used, otherwise there is always manual marshalling.

Comment: BurnsBA No, my code does not display it correctly. The whole question is how to display it correctly...

Comment: xanatos, the C/C++ code has this draconian Swig interface. It is a forest. All I can show is this: string txt = msg.GetInstantMessage().htmlBody;public OpalInstantMessage GetInstantMessage() {
    global::System.IntPtr cPtr = OPALPINVOKE.OpalMessagePtr_GetInstantMessage(swigCPtr);
    OpalInstantMessage ret = (cPtr == global::System.IntPtr.Zero) ? null : new OpalInstantMessage(cPtr, false);
    return ret;
  }

Comment: If you look at `cómo` in utf-8, you get (as bytes) `63 C3 B3 6D 6F`.  If I decode that to Windows 1252 or to UTF-7, I end up with `cÃ³mo`.  Someone is doing encoding/decoding behind your back

Comment: @Leon Ok... The decoding is done inside the constructor of `OpalInstantMessage(IntPtr, bool)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok... The problem is that your C/C++ dll is one of the rare C/C++ dlls that instead of using the standard Windows "Ansi" encoding uses utf8... cheers ... sadly .NET thinks that it is using Windows "Ansi" encoding... cheers  (this was sarcastic)...

So you have to reverse the "damage" done... There is no guarantee that the damage can be undone, it depends on your `Encoding.Default`, but if you are using the Windows-1252 (you are probably Spanish, right?) it should be possible to simply:

```
string txt = "cÃ³mo";
byte[] bytes = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(txt);
string txt2 = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
```

The "perfect" solution would be to change the pinvoke "configuration", but you are using Swig, that is an hell all in itself (a hell that I'm more than happy to not know )

Comment: xanatos, I really appreciate your response. I do not know what C# WinForms app uses by default - never had a problem like that and was not curious. I doubt if it is "Windows-1252" (since I am not Spanish). I will try you code right away.

Comment: @Leon `Encoding.Default.EncodingName` will give you the name